# When using FusionCharts I am not able to remove decimals from the y-axis values being used

Tags: jquery, fusioncharts

I have a simple bar chart and for the y-axis it is showing decimals. Because this chart only works with whole numbers (you can't have .5 person for example), I want the chart to only divide the y-axis using whole number and not fractions. I have tried adding the following and it doesn't change anything.

adjustDiv: "0", yAxisValueDecimals: "0", forceYAxisValueDecimals: "0",

Here is my full script (I'm using JQuery):

```
                    $('#chart-container1').insertFusionCharts({
                        type: 'column3d',
                        width: '100%',
                        dataFormat: 'json',
                        dataSource: {
                            chart: {
                                caption: settings.Caption,
                                xAxisName: "Regions",
                                yAxisName: "Incidents",
                decimals: "0",
                                numberSuffix: "",
                                showvalues: "0",
                                adjustDiv: "0",
                                yAxisValueDecimals: "0",
                                forceYAxisValueDecimals: "0",
                                theme: "zune"

                            },
                            data: chartData

                        }
                    });
                }
```

Adding these params to remove decimals from the y-axis values:

adjustDiv: "0", yAxisValueDecimals: "0", forceYAxisValueDecimals: "0",

I am using version 3.17